# Emulate devices with headless_chrome

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I'm trying to emulate different devices when running my specs, with no results for now.

```
#spec_helper

require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium
 browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
 browser_options.args << '--headless'

 mobile_emulation = { "deviceName" => "iPhone 8" }
 capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
   "chromeOptions" => { "mobileEmulation" => mobile_emulation }
 )

 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options, desired_capabilities: capabilities)
end
```

Should I include the `mobile_emulation` part in the Options instead of Capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chromeOptions` is no longer a valid key (it was replaced with `goog:chromeOptions`) but since you're already using the `::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options` class you should just use the `add_emulation` method - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Chrome/Options#add_emulation-instance_method -on that.

```
browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
browser_options.args << '--headless'
browser_options.add_emulation(device_name: 'iPhone 8')

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I change to `goog:chromeOptions`?

Comment: @fabersky It will probably work currently, but swapping to using the Options class is the preferred method and will future-proof your code

Comment: But which would be the appropriate method in that case?